# How to make base generic type know child generic in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, generics, interface, typescript

is there a way to make two generics type in a base one , but also make one of them contain the second one as generic?

this is my code:

```
interface ITreeNode extends IBaseNode{
}

interface IBaseTree<T extends IBaseNode> {
    nodeType: T
}

interface IBaseForest <T extends IBaseTree<T2 extends IBaseNode>> {
    treeType: T
    nodeType: T2 
}
```

the problem is 'T2 extends IBaseNode' , i cant really set another type, in theory I don't need to, because the baseTree knows the type of his node , i cant get the forest understand who is this node.

i am sorry if i am not understandable, and thank you for any of your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified a bit.

- Removed `IBaseNode` since its wasn't declared and not relevant to our problem. Think of `ITreeNode` as your base node
- Use generic placholder names to match the intent (e.g. `K,V` in dictionaries). Here the intent is `Node` : `N` and `Tree` : `T`

So the following does what I *think* you want:

```
interface ITreeNode{}

interface IBaseTree<N extends ITreeNode> {
    nodeType: N;
}

interface IBaseForest<N extends ITreeNode,T> {
    treeType: T;
    nodeType: N;
}
```

However if you want to contraint `T` as well based on `N` you can't because of the limitation shown below:

[image]

Which is according to spec.

Comment: your answer is working , i guess i'm trying to do something i can't, the forest should hold the same node type as the tree and i cant figure out how to declare it correctly cause in this scenerio node type can be different in the two places.

also when i initialize interface that extend forest but with base classes...its make the declaration very very clumsy

interface IAmazonForest extends IBaseForest<ITreeNode, IBaseTree<ITreeNode>>